# Customize itemize with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

I would like to customize the itemize environment with TikZ rectangle.

Problem : the second itemize is not as expected... (cf. code below).

Thanks for your help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{my_itemize}{%
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\tikz \node[fill = red]{} ;}\begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{my_itemize_bis}{%
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\tikz \node[fill = blue]{} ;}\begin{itemize}}
    {\end{itemize}} 


\begin{document}

\begin{my_itemize}
\item hello

    \begin{my_itemize_bis}
    \item hello bis
    \end{my_itemize_bis}
    
\end{my_itemize}

\end{document}

``
```

Comment: You missed a second i at the second `\labelitemii` it should be and not `\labelitemi`

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Needless to use a hammersledge like tikz for that: using enumitem and amssymb does the job:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \newlist{my_itemize}{itemize}{2}
    \setlist[my_itemize, 1]{label = \color{red}$\blacksquare$}
    \setlist[my_itemize, 2]{label = \color{blue}$\blacksquare$}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{my_itemize}
    \item hello

        \begin{my_itemize}
        \item hello bis
        \end{my_itemize}

    \end{my_itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]